# Angular - Error when trying to overwrite sortingDataAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, angular-material-table

I want to overwrite `sortingDataAccessor` to make sorting my table work with all of its columns. However, I keep running into `error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Job'`.
Here is how I am trying to overwrite the `sortingDataAccessor`:

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  switch (property) {
    case "date":
      return item.jobDate;

    default:
      return item[property];
  }
};
```

The error is being thrown here:
`item[property]`

What am I doing wrong and how can I properly overwrite this function without getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `string` type of the `property` parameter is a bit too broad for your needs. So this `property` can be any string whatsoever, but the keys that you can use to index the `Job` type is a limited collection of strings. You can instruct the compiler to *think* that the `property` will be a valid indexer for your `item` by telling it that:

```
return item[property as keyof Job];
```

You could also do something a bit more creative, like saving the current `sortingDataAccessor` in a variable before assigning your custom handler, and then using it for all the other properties for which you don't want to override the default behavior:

```
const originalSortingDataAccessor = this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor;

this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  switch (property) {
    case "date":
      return item.jobDate as any;

    default:
      return originalSortingDataAccessor(item, property);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately, when I try this I now get the following error:
Type '(item: Job, property: string) => string | number | boolean | Date | TranslatedString' is not assignable to type '(data: Job, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number'. This error is now thrown here: `this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor`. Do I now have to somehow exclude the attributes which I already handle separately from the `keyof Job`, or what is going on here?

Comment: @Chris They seem to leave them as `any` in [the default sorting data accessor implementation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/23f392995c791f3585cf816d9249d6f83143f52c/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts#L154). You should be fine by placing `as any` on the return values.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error but it seems like the `property` has the type `string` and this type cannot be used to access a property of the `Job` class. However, I would need to see how this class looks in order to say more about this.

Generally, you can resolve the problem with some type-casting e.g. `(item, property: any) => {...}`